# C++ - Template subclass inherits from multiple template classes

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I am creating a simple class named `HashMap`:

```
template <typename K,typename V> class HashMap{
    .
    .
    .
    public:

        class Hashable;
```

I created another class:

```
template<typename T> class Stack;
```

Now I must create a new class (`NewStackClass`), which extends `Stack` and `HashMap<K,V>::Hashable`.

Objects of this class are meant to be instantiated when K=Stack/NewStackClass.

Example:

```
HashMap<NewStackClass<int>,int> map;
//T=int;K=NewStackClass<int>;V=int;
```

or:

```
HashMap<Stack<char>,int> map;
//T=char;K=Stack<char>;V=int;
```

How can I obtain this? Also, I want to split class declaration from its implementation.

I already tried with this:

```
template <typename B, typename C>
template <typename A> class NewStackClass : public Stack<A>, public HashMap<B,C>::Hashable{

    virtual int hashCode() const;
    bool operator==(const MyStack<A>& stack);
};
```

but it didn't work:

> [Error] too many template-parameter-lists

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

Creating NewStackclass:

```
    template <typename StackType,typename HashMapValue> class MyStack : public NewStackClass<StackType>, public HashMap<Stack<StackType>,HashMapValue>::Hashable{

        virtual int hashCode() const {

            return 1;
        }

        bool operator==(const NewStackClass<StackType,HashMapValue>& stack){

            return true;
        }
    };
```

Let's get in the private area of `HashMap` class:

```
private:

    int hash(const Hashable& key) const{

        return (31*17 +key.hashCode()) % TABLE_SIZE;
    }
```

Doing this in main.cpp:

```
HashMap<NewStackClass<int,int>,int> map1;

NewStackClass<int,int> stack;
map1.put(stack,0);
```

Brings out this error:

```
[Error] no matching function for call to "HashMap<NewStackClass<int, int>, int>::hash(const NewStackClass<int, int>&)"
```

Error comes from this:

> [Note] no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const NewStackClass' to 'const HashMap, int>::Hashable&'

Comment: What do you mean *it didn't work*? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: [Error] too many template-parameter-lists

Answer (score 3):

Your code contains a syntactical flaw. You may only have a single template parameter list for your class.

merge

```
template <typename B, typename C>
template <typename A> class NewStackClass ...
```

to this

```
template <typename B, typename C, typename A>
class NewStackClass ...
```

to make it compile.
Also you did not provide information on what `MyStack` is supposed to be. I just assume that you meant to write `Stack` instead.

You should also think about whether your class `NewStackClass` really needs three template arguments or if there are actually only two distinct ones.

Judging by your question, your might want to do:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
class NewStackClass : public Stack<K>, public HashMap<Stack<K>,V>::Hashable {
```

instead.

### Fixed Code (Syntax Only)

```
template <typename K,typename V>
class HashMap {
public:
    class Hashable {
    };
};

template<typename T> class Stack {
};

template <typename B, typename C, typename A>
class NewStackClass : public Stack<A>, public HashMap<B,C>::Hashable {

    virtual int hashCode() const;
    bool operator==(const Stack<A>& stack);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however i would like to remove the B parameter, if possible, in order to make B= NewStackClass<A> (as you suggested).

Furthermore, operator== prototype get's incorrect since compiler complains about giving just one template parameter.

Comment: If your intention was to compare two instances of `NewStackClass`, then you will have to pass a parameter with the exact same template parameters to the operator==(...). Since your `NewStackClass` has two template parameters, your operator should look like `bool operator==(const NewStackClass<K, V>& stack)`.

Comment: It compiles now, but using HashMap<Stack<K>,V> doesn't let me use the hashCode() method, which belongs to Hashable interface (MyStack extends it, not Stack) i'm going to post new code in a few minutes

Comment: Please check out my post edits, and still thanks for your help.